# Back Button Navigation

Tags: caliburn.micro

Is there a way to use navigation service that Caliburn provides with back button on windows phone. I have a universal app and am using Caliburn Micro beta 2. The application has couple of views. I want to use back button for navigating back from one screen to another and only way right now seems to be manually using following in each page-

Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;

Also I am using Caliburn's navigation service to navigate from one viewmodel to other. Even if I navigate to another view model, the Windows.Current.Content never changes from one view to other. This then doesnt cause proper back navigation when I use following code-

```
void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    if (rootFrame != null && rootFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        rootFrame.GoBack();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Not sure if there is a more elegant way to enable this functionality.

Thanks